# how to open a landscape view from a portrait view

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, uikit, ipad

I have a portrait view showing a library of images, clicking on an image should open it in landscape view for editing. Now I know I could manually rotate the new view 90 degrees to make it “look” like it is in landscape but isn’t there a proper solution? e.g. somehow I could force the device to go into landscape mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tuns out I'll have to manually rotate my views or at least my findings suggest so. So here's what I am doing now:

- Show the first view in Portrait Mode.
- When user goes to the next view, I manually apply a transform to it to rotate it PI/2 radians and set its frame and center properties.

Answer (score 0):

Push a modal view controller which is configured to only support landscape mode.

Comment: actually, i can’t push, i have a custom controller that replace’s views as required. so essentially no new view controller is pushed, it’s one view controller with different views.

Comment: also, this only works for first view controller that gets pushed (or the root controller). It doesn't work in case you want the first view controller to be portrait and the next to be in landscape. guess manually doing the rotation is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

To force the device to go to landscape mode, you can add

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
        {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
        }`

Adding this to the view you want to display in landscape should make the view come in landscape mode...

Comment: looking at documentation for `UIView`, there isn't a `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, If you are talking about overriding it in the `UIViewController`, I already mentioned in the comment to Andrew's reply that It doesn't work unless the view controller gets pushed.

Comment: don't know why you got an upvote when there is no such method in the `UIView`